# PWA with ionic and capacitor, native plugin complains cordova not available, on browser and device

Tags: cordova, progressive-web-apps, ionic4, ionic-native, capacitor

I am developing a PWA with ionic 4.12 and Capacitor, I  would like to use the native plugin ImagePicker; I followed this guide https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker, when I run imagePicker.getPicture, get this error "cordova not available" both on browser and on the device, I do not know how to make working the plugin, thanks in advance.

Comment: what device where you running on ? web isnt a suported platform for this plugin

Comment: on my android  mobile  phone and on my computer

Comment: It may be that the plugin isnt compatible with capacitor ? not entirely sure how to check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova plugins are not supported on PWAs yet

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/769